# Multiple image comparison using OpenCV Python

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I tried comparing two images using diff function in OpenCV Python, but I am not able to compare one image with the images stored in my test folder.
 So how can I compare one input image with my test images saved in a folder using OpenCV Python?

Comment: Can you show what have you tried so far?

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you are trying to determine. Should a red 100x100 pixel square saved as a PNG be found to be the same as a red 100x100 pixel square saved as a JPEG? Because those two files will have totally different size and contents. If I create a 64x64 pixel black square in Photoshop and save it as a PNG, then save it a second time with a different name, should the two files be recognised as identical? They will not be if you checksum them because the PNG format saves the date/time which will be a few seconds different...

Comment: Thank you for reply. Actually all my images are in jpeg format only. What I want to know is how to compare one image one by one with my test images in folder.

Answer (score 1):

```
from PIL import Image
image1 = Image.open("image1.png")
image2 = Image.open("image2.png")

assert image1.size == image2.size, "Images are of Different sizes."

pairs = zip(image1.getdata(), image2.getdata())
dif = sum(abs(c1-c2) for p1,p2 in pairs for c1,c2 in zip(p1,p2))

ncomponents = image1.size[0] * image1.size[1] * 3
print("Difference (percentage):", (dif / 255.0 * 100) / ncomponents)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me :

```html
from PIL import Image

i1 = Image.open('./image_1.png')

for i in range(18):
 i2 = Image.open('./image_%s.png'% i)
 pairs = zip(i1.getdata(), i2.getdata())
 if len(i1.getbands()) == 1:
  # for gray-scale jpegs
  dif = sum(abs(p1-p2) for p1,p2 in pairs)
 else:
  dif = sum(abs(c1-c2) for p1,p2 in pairs for c1,c2 in zip(p1,p2))
 ncomponents = i1.size[0] * i1.size[1] * 3
 print ("Difference (percentage):", (dif / 255.0 * 100) / ncomponents)
```

it will compare all the images present in the folder which are having the name "image_(int value)"

OUTPUT:

```html
Difference (percentage): 0.5852243327886709
Difference (percentage): 1.1135548577069718
Difference (percentage): 1.1761242170479302
.
.
.
.
```